# MySQL joining multiple columns from table 1 to multiple columns on table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Right so here's my problem,
I have 2 tables, orderentry and standardexpenses
orderentry (as O) looks something like

```
ORDERNO | FROMSTATIONCODE | TOSTATIONCODE
```

and standardexpenses as (SE) looks like

```
FROMSTATION | TOSTATION | TOTALAMOUNT | CURRENCY (which is either in MT or USD)
```

I've figured out how to convert the currency already using

```
ROUND(SUM(IF(SE.CURRENCY='MT',SE.TOTALAMOUNT*0.0336,SE.TOTALAMOUNT)),2)
```

what i want to know is how i could join the `O.FROMSTATIONCODE` and `O.TOSTATIONCODE` to the `SE.FROMSTATION` and `SE.TOSTATION` ...BUT still being able to calculate the `SUM(TOTALAMOUNT).`

Because right now my code is

```
SELECT 
    FROMSTATION,
    TOSTATION,
    SUM(TOTALAMOUNT),
    COUNT(TOTALAMOUNT),
    CURRENCY
FROM STANDARDEXPENSES
JOIN ORDERENTRY AS O 
    ON STANDARDEXPENSES.FROMSTATION = O.FROMSTATIONCODE
    AND STANDARDEXPENSES.TOSTATION = O.TOSTATIONCODE
GROUP BY FROMSTATION,TOSTATION,CURRENCY
```

Note: eg. SE has 5 different expenses from destination1 to destionation2 and ORDERENTRY has 12

`ORDERNO` from destination1 to destionation2, I want to use the total of the 5 expenses
(after conversion) and apply it to ALL 12 ORDERNO so that they each show the same TOTALAMOUNT.

right now i try it and it gives me what seems to be random multiples rather than the actual amount.

Comment: You can edit your question instead of posting e-mails to us if we need additional details.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: So what actual RDBMS are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Why both tags are present on question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works on MySQL but you could try something like this. If the problem is how to convert the currency values in your aggregation of TOTALAMOUNT.

```
SELECT 
FROMSTATION,
TOSTATION,
CASE CURRENCY WHEN 'MT' THEN 0.0336 ELSE 1.00 END AS FX_RATE,
ROUND(SUM(TOTALAMOUNT*FX_RATE),2),
COUNT(TOTALAMOUNT),
CURRENCY
FROM STANDARDEXPENSES
JOIN ORDERENTRY AS O 
ON STANDARDEXPENSES.FROMSTATION = O.FROMSTATIONCODE
AND STANDARDEXPENSES.TOSTATION = O.TOSTATIONCODE
GROUP BY FROMSTATION,TOSTATION,CURRENCY
```